# SSH not landing in the home directory

Tags: linux, ssh, users, home, raspberry-pi

I have recently installed Raspbian into a Raspberry Pi. As part of the installation process I changed the user name and group from the default (`pi`) to my own (let's call it `user`) using `usermod` and `groupmod`. I also moved the home directory (`/home/pi`) to the new user name (`/home/user`) using `usermod`. Everything works fine except that when I login using SSH instead of landing the new user directory (`/home/user`) I end up at the home directory (`/home`). Any idea why this may be happening? Any solution? It's not a big deal but it is confusing me.

The directory `/home/user` exists with permissions 755. In addition to that the `/etc/passwd` file contains an entry that looks like the following:

```
user:x:1000:1000:User:/home/user:/bin/bash
```

To me everything looks fine, but still when I login from ssh I get a prompt that looks like `user@raspberrypi /home $`.

Comment: You may have better luck with this question at the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MichaelHampton [raspberrypi.se] tends to migrate questions purely about software to [unix.se], actually. I think this question would be considered off-topic on [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: What's the content of your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` (if they exist)? If you run `ssh raspberrypi pwd` and `ssh raspberrypi 'echo ~'`, what does it show?

Comment: I tried both your commands and both return `/home/user` (where user is the actual username). The contents of the other files (they do exist) is the default that comes with Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4):

did you use the `-m` option when you used `usermod -d` ?

if not, then you need to actually move the home directory as well as change the entry in /etc/passwd.

This will rename /home/pi to /home/user if /home/user does not already exist:

```
cd /home
[ ! -e user ] && sudo mv pi user
```

oterwise, check that `user`'s home directory is actually `/home/user` and not just `/home`...here are some of the methods you can use to find out a user's home dir:

```
grep '^user:' /etc/passwd      # works for system-local accounts only

finger user                    # requires finger to be installed

pinky -l user                  # part of GNU coreutils

getent passwd user             # should work no matter where the account
                                 data is stored
```

Comment: The directory **/home/user** exists with permissions 755. In addition to that the **/etc/passwd** file contains an entry that looks like the following: **user:x:1000:1000:User:/home/user:/bin/bash**. To me everything looks fine, but still when I login from ssh I get a prompt that looks like **user@raspberrypi /home $**. Any further ideas?

Comment: very odd.  have you checked your log file to see if there are any error/warning messages from sshd?  try /var/log/messages, /var/log/syslog and/or /var/log/auth.log

Comment: also, what happens when you type `cd` and hit enter (it should take you to your home dir).

Comment: also, i just noticed that you said the prompt says `... /home $`.  did you check if that's correct? it might just be a problem with your prompt string, $PS1 .  run `pwd` to print the current working directory name.

Comment: Also, what is the **ownership** of /home/user?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem using Raspbian.
After adding a user named "bill", raspbian failed to create the user's home directory.
Although I had created the user account using "useradd bill && passwd bill", and although the /etc/passwd file contained the expected path to /home/bill as the home directory, the actual path "/home/bill" was never created.
I had to manually create /home/bill as root, and then use chmod and chown to change the permissions and ownership to the right value.
Now when I log on as "bill" using ssh, I end up in the "/" directory rather than in /home/bill.  The /home/bill/.bashrc file does not do any trickery to change the directory from the default value of /home/bill.

It would appear that raspbian doesn't work the way that every other linux distribution works.  This is clearly a BUG.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior in TrueNAS (FreeBSD).

- Edited user in /etc/passwd to have homedir `/path/newhome`
- Logged out of SSH, logged back in and received `Could not chdir to home directory /path/oldhome`
- Was able to `chdir /path/newhome` without issue

This may need a system restart to take effect, but this isn't a system I can restart on a whim.

As a workaround, you can just run `chdir /path/newhome` after logging in. Crude, but effective.

Comment: What's `chdir`? This reads more like a comment than an answer, or possibly like a follow-up question.

Comment: I thought `chdir` could be used to (basically) change the path of ~ which would make it a viable work-around, but I was mistaken. I'm going to delete the reply as it is effectively a comment.